# Nunit running tests in parallel not working

Tags: unit-testing, parallel-processing, asp.net-core, nunit, nunit-3.0

I added `[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]` to my AssemblyInfo.cs.

now I'm running the test `dotnet test` and see in logs that test executed in normal order (fixture after fixture, in alphabetical order, not mixed, although I have 130 tests in 10 test fixtures).
also - tests run time didnt changed. 
so, what can be the reason? thanks!

nunit version 3.5

asp.net core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running .NET Core tests, you are using the NUnit portable framework build, which does not upport parallel execution. The attribute is still accepted so that you can switch to different platform builds without changing the code.